# new Item not inserting in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: library, libraries

I am facing a problem when i am creating new Row into a SharePoint 2013 List.

Error:
 I am unable to insert any row into SharePoint List Library, through C# Or Java Script Code and **also i am unable to insert direct from list library is taking to much time  ( time around 1 minute)  to insert a new row in any Mode.** 
for your reference see below image.

[image]

Please Help me out to solve this issue,

I have checked all Services **Manage Services on Server** which all are started.

I have Multiple HostName Site Collection where i am getting this issue other normal site list working fine.

Comment: How many items are in the list?

Comment: Great! Would you post the solution as an answer to your own question to help out others that come across this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I already Resolved this problem when i Raised the Question, So today i am posting the solution.

The Problem was in my all list in which i am using workflows,

below Services are responsible to communicate with workflow Client & manager farms. 
After Reboot the server these services didn't start if causing the error.

I started first tow services and restarted windows Fabric Host Service, after that all are working fine.

1. Service Bus Gateway
2. Service Bus Message Broker
3. windows Fabric Host Service

I hope this can be help someone in need.

[image]

[image]